# How to open the "**sdcard files in android**" and if i click the file it must open in emulator?

Tags: android, pdf

How to open the "**sdcard files in android**"  and if i click the file it must open in emulator?

Comment: First google it your query. If you don't have anything from there means, after that ask here as a question.

Comment: Dont ask for Source Code here man!!!

Comment: Please you need to go through this site before posting questions here http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Testopen extends Activity {
    private List<String> list;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "mymusic" //folder name
        );
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        list = getSD();
        lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
        Log.d("LOG", "FIRE !!!! " );  

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(Testopen.this,"clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Testopen.this, OpenFileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    //read from sdcard
    private List<String> getSD() {
        List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File("/sdcard/download");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            //take the file name only
            long size = file.length()/1024;

            String myfile = file.getPath().substring(file.getPath().lastIndexOf("/")+1,file.getPath().length()).toLowerCase(); 
            //item.add(myfile);
            item.add(myfile+"             "+"Size:"+size+" KB");

            // Log.d("LOG", "fs "+file.length());
            //item.add(file.length());
        }
        return item;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code -

Extends ListActivity.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int clickCounter=0;
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    private File[] imagelist;
    String[] pdflist;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
            imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
                    {  
                            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));  
                    }  
            }); 
            pdflist = new String[imagelist.length]; 
            for(int i = 0;i<imagelist.length;i++)
            {
                    pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
            }
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
             Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
             List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
             if (list.size() > 0 && imagelist[(int) id].isFile()) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagelist[(int) id].getAbsoluteFile());
                 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
    }
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i got the following error 12-28 11:42:43.345: E/AndroidRuntime(344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Pdf}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: ya working.But It shows all the pdf files in sd card.when i click the pdf file nothig can done.do u have any pdf viewer code?

Comment: No, Just run this in sdcard. And, also install some pdf viewer to your emulator. And, before accept my answer if it's working?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something similar to a File Explorer. Check out the below link. It might be helpful.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html